# Automatic Image Deploy from Network to Multiple Different Machines

Tags: networking, boot, automation, disk-image

We have multiple different "computers" that uses SD card like drives to store Windows. Those Windows are written to those cards with [HDD Raw Copy](http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-Raw-Copy-Tool/).

Every couple of weeks we manually

1. Write those .img, .imgc files to cards from a PC
2. Insert it to device and boot
3. Install new version of a software
4. Take away card to a PC and take backup with HDD Raw Copy
5. Re-insert it to device
6. Do some tests

Every device have different image and installed software.
Devices are different but have static IP's and their image rarely changes.

I want to automate everything beside the last step, How can I do this?
I am also open to other approaches.

P.S: I read about PXE but I am not sure it is applicable to my situation

Answer (score 0):

PXE requires the client to be able to retrieve the image at boot time - if that's possible it's probably the easiest solution.

Distributing the images over the network and writing them to local storage is another option. You've give no details, so it's hard to say how to do it.

You can run either client or server on the device, using a server would have the advantage that you can run updates at any time from your distribution server (as TFPT or SFTP client). Using the device as client requires them to initiate the update.

Alternative to distributing images, you could also have the 'computers' update themselves through a patch.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the information you need?